# What is "lax cardia"?

Tags: digestion, gastroenterology, stomach, gerd-acid-reflux, flatulence-gas-fart

My upper GI endoscopy report impression says: lax cardia, grade a relux oesophagitis, erosive gastritis. What is "lax cardia"?

My symptoms: abdomen pain around belly button, weight loss, belching etc..

What is my disease?[image]